# Return a value from lambda to the global method C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lambda

I have a method with two callbacks. One for error and one for success. 
Currently it looks like this:

```
private resultObject makeMyRequest()
{
    requestObject request = new requestObject();

    MakeRequest(request, (result) =>
    {
        return result;
    }, (error) => {
        return null;

    });
}
```

The issue here is at the two return statements. They are trying to return the lambda expression. But what I want them to do is to return to the "makeMyRequest" method. How can this be done? And more so, if it's done. That would make a very slow method. Is there a way to do this "async" or similarly. I am currently working in a .NET 2.0 environment so I do not have access to some newer async techniques.

Comment: What does `MakeRequest()` return?

Comment: what is `MakeRequest`'s signature?

Comment: @haim770 Well, its a method that can fail or succed. It's a web request. If it fails it simply returns a error object. But i dont mind that as In that case I just want to return null as my example above. But if it succeeds it will return a "resultObject" just like the global method.

Comment: A "callback" implies that it's an asynchronous operation.  What exactly are you attempting to "return" from that?  Isn't the enclosing method already done before the callback happens?

Comment: @David oh sorry, Yes. it is asyncronous. But I am attempting to return the "result" varaible that is of type "resultObject".

Comment: @TwoTen: "Return" it to *where*?  I'm not sure you're entirely familiar with what the word "asynchronous" means.  It sounds like you've taken a wrong turn somewhere in your design before you got to this question.

Comment: @David Well. If MakeRequest method runs it will callback a lambda method and result is passed in as parameter. I want to return that from the lambda method to the global method. Wich means the global method will have to wait until my async operation is done and have completed its callback

Comment: @TwoTen: And does `MakeRequest()` *return* this information?  Does it have any return value at all?  Can you modify it to work synchronously and return the result?  You can't force `MakeRequest()` to return something without modifying that method itself.  But since you claim that you want to perform this task synchronously then I guess you would need to modify `MakeRequest` to be synchronous instead of asynchronous.

Comment: @David MakeRequest() returns void. The callbacks is what gives me the value. That's where the issue is. I dont neccecarly need to perform it sync. But i'm just guessing thats easier as the makeMyRequest method wont know when MakeRequest is actually finished and the callbacks have been called.

Comment: @TwoTen: A `void` method can't return anything.  You either need to re-write `MakeRequest()` to be synchronous and return a result or you need to adjust your approach to use the asynchronous version.  You can't have both.

Comment: @David how would I use the async version to perform what I need?

Comment: @TwoTen: Depends on what you need.  So far you've only defined the need as "return a result", which can't happen.  What is it that you actually need to accomplish here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need something like this:

```
private resultObject makeMyRequest()
{
    requestObject request = new requestObject();

    resultObject returnValue = null

    MakeRequest(request, 
        (result) =>  { returnValue = result; },
        (error) => { });

    return returnValue;
}
```

(This only works if MakeRequest(...) is syncronious.)

This should do the trick if MakeRequest is async:

```
private resultObject makeMyRequest()
{
    requestObject request = new requestObject();

    AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false); 
    resultObject returnValue = null

    MakeRequest(request, 
        (result) =>  { 
            returnValue = result; 
            autoEvent.Set(); 
        },
        (error) => { 
            autoEvent.Set();
        });

    autoEvent.WaitOne();

    return returnValue;
}
```

Remark: if you don't want the thread to block you can return a custom object containing the auto reset event and the result, so you can wait for it later.

Full blown example

```
private async resultObject makeMyRequest()
{
    requestObject request = new requestObject();

    var returnValue = new PromiseResult(new AutoResetEvent(false));         

    MakeRequest(request, 
        (result) =>  { 
            returnValue.Result = result; 
            returnValue.Event.Set(); 
        },
        (error) => { 
            returnValue.Event.Set();
        });


    return returnValue;
}


public class PromiseResult {
    public resultObject Result {get;set;}
    public AutoResetEvent Event {get;}

    public PromiseResult(AutoResetEvent are){
        Event = are;
    }       
}

public class Example{

    public void Test(){

        var promise = makeMyRequest();

        while(true){

            if (promise.Event.WaitOne(0)){
                Console.WriteLine(promise.Result);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not ready yet ..., but the thread is free to do some other stuff");
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I need. (The bottom version). Do you mind showing me a example of a non thread blocking version? What would be in the object etc as I cannot use mulitple threads nor block the main thread for the environment im working in. Thanks

Comment: Thanks alot, just one problem. as stated in my original question I am using  .NET 2.0. I get the following errors just from the class: "Feature 'readonly automatically implemented properties' is not available in C# 4. Please use language version 6 or greater.

Comment: I think that was the line `public AutoResetEvent Event {get; }` just adding the `set;` should solve that.

Comment: Oh yes, that solved that part. Now to the actual method. "Features 'async fumction' is not available in C# 4. Please use language version 5 or greater".

Comment: I don't understand this error, but I .NET framework and C# language versions are two different things. You can upgrade your Visual Studio to use the latest C# language version. That should not affect your solution (/build) at all

Comment: Well, I am not entierly sure. It's for a game using the Unity game engine. so I cannot affect what C# language it's using. I have the latest visual studio. I need to use things like Task factorys (Not entierly sure how they work) for things like this I beleive. Not the async statement.

Comment: But we don't use the async statement at all... Did you write the MakeRequest function yourself? and could you post the signature? (by editing your question)

Comment: Line one in your full blown example? And no, I did not write the method myself.

Comment: Oops, just remove the async keyword

Comment: Seems like it's still blocking my thread. I am doing exactly what you are in your test method

Comment: The test method will block because it calls the Promise.Event.WaitOne() function. remove that and the Console.WriteLine method to stop bloking the thread

Comment: Well then the Console Writeline is simply throwing a NullReferenceException instantly when called

Comment: You are not allowed to use the result before calling the .WaitOne() . Async just means you can do some other things while you are waiting for the result. But if you need it, you have to wait for it = block the thread

Comment: Oh. So when should I call WaitOne. Cause currently it completly freezes my application and does not respond and I have to force close it.

Comment: If you are in a game I suppose there is a constant loop running. you could store the promise in some variable and call promise.Event.WaitOne(0) which will return a boolean indicating if the result is ready. Of course I cannot give you a test method that will not block the loop. But I will update the example so you can see how the check works

Comment: Ps: I just write this code in notepad, so if there is a little typo somewhere you must forgive me :)